# Trying to show a percentage in a cross-object report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, cross-object

I've created a report that shows all Accounts with or without Contacts. I need to show the percentage of accounts with contacts (while still showing a record count), but none of the formulas I have tried work for what I am trying to achieve. I've tried:

• (RowCount / PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount,Contact.Name)) *100

• (Account.Name/Contact.Name) * 100

• (Account.Name:SUM)/PARENTGROUPVAL(Contact.Name:SUM) *100

The biggest problem so far is recognizing the Contact.Name field, but I'm pulling from available fields in the formula editor, so I'm not sure where I'm messing up there.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a custom report type with the following settings:

[image: settings]

Then I would create a formula field on Contact with a default value of 1:

[image: Power of One]

Then I would group my report by this new field that I created, dividing the results into records with and without Contact:

[image]

Finally, I'd create a new Summary Formula:

[image]

And add it to the report:

[image]

As we can see in the report Grand Summary, only 1 of my 20 Accounts has a Contact, which gives a value of 5%.

Comment: Thanks so much! This looks to be just what I need. Have a great day today!

Comment: @ChristinHead Kindly accept my answer for this question if the solution to your answer is correct. Otherwise you can reply in this comment section if it does not work for you.

Comment: Okay, so it works as needed in contacts , but we cannot get the same method to work in other objects - specifically, opportunity and a custom object. Is there a reason for this? I've created the PoO field on both objects, and incorporated it into the reports. The formula wizard will not recognize "Opportunity.PowerofOne__c:SUM / RowCount" or "Sales_And_Market__c.PowerofOne__c:SUM / RowCount"

Comment: Any ideas are much appreciated. Thank you!